# loop through rows and columns to meet criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I would be very greatful if someone could help me with this issue...

I would like to have a excel macro which would go through first row and first column of the sheet2 to return the value if booth conditions are met in cell b3 in sheet1.
Conditions would be specified on sheet1; cell b1 would contain condition by which rows in sheet2 should be searched and cell b2 would contain condition by which columns in sheet2 should be searched. Result should be copied in cell b3 in sheet1.

Thanks in advance

Addition..............

I have this sub which goes through rows and looks for condition 1 (strDate) but I only managed to do this is column is fixed. I should add one more counter which would go through columns to meet condition 2 (strProduct) but I don

```
   Sub LookUpValuesRCC2()
'
Dim shtData     As Worksheet    ' Sheet containing data 
Dim shtOutput   As Worksheet    ' Output Sheet 
Dim strDate     As String       ' Date - condition 1
Dim strProduct  As String       ' Product - condition 2   
Dim i           As Integer      ' Counter in shtData Sheet
Dim j           As Integer      ' Counter in shtOutput Sheet
'
Set shtData = Worksheets("sheet2")
Set shtOutput = Worksheets("sheet1")
'
' Loop through "Data" Sheet Rows
For i = 1 To 1000

    strDate = shtData.Cells(i, 1)
    '
    ' Loop through dates in "Output" Sheet
    ' if date match then vrite values
    For j = 1 To shtOutput.Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row
        If shtOutput.Cells(j, 14) = strDate Then
            shtOutput.Cells(j, 2) = shtData.Cells(i, 18)

        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First welcome to SO. Second, it's not 100% clear what your after because your code doesn't exactly match the description of what you want, or doesn't appear to me to do that.

I've written the below code based on what your description says, since the code you have doesn't get you want you want, so I am going to assume it needs modification anyway.

Comment if this doesn't satisfy your requirement.

```
Sub LookUpValuesRCC2()

Dim shtData     As Worksheet    ' Sheet containing data
Dim shtOutput   As Worksheet    ' Output Sheet
Dim strDate     As Date       ' Date - condition 1
Dim strProduct  As String       ' Product - condition 2
Dim strResult As String         'result to print

Dim rngFound As range, rngFoundAgain As range

Set shtData = Worksheets("sheet2")
Set shtOutput = Worksheets("sheet1")

strDate = shtOutput.range("B1").Value
strProduct = shtOutput.range("B2").Value

strResult = "Nothing Found"

With shData

    'first look down the first column for the date
    Set rngFound = .Columns(1).Find(strDate, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then

        'if that is found, look for the product in the row with the date
        Set rngFoundAgain = rngFound.EntireRow.Find(strProduct, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not rngFoundAgain Is Nothing Then strResult = rngFoundAgain.Value

    End If

End With

shtData.range("B3") = strResult


End Sub
```